# How to remove spaces before and after a string?

Tags: php, regex

I have two words spirited by space of course, and a lot of spaces before and after,
what I need to do is to remove the before and after spaces without the in between once.

How can I remove the spaces before and after it?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You don't need regex for that, use [trim()](http://php.net/trim):

```
$words = '      my words     ';
$words = trim($words);
var_dump($words);
// string(8) "my words"
```

*This function returns a string with whitespace stripped from the beginning and end of str.*

Comment: How come this didn't work for me ? I still see my white spaces after the strings. Any hints ? Anyone ?

Comment: Maybe they are not really whitespaces. I encountered this problem with texts from Office Word.

Answer (score 7):

For completeness (as this question is tagged `regex`), here is a `trim()` reimplementation in regex:

```
function preg_trim($subject) {
    $regex = "/\s*(\.*)\s*/s";
    if (preg_match ($regex, $subject, $matches)) {
        $subject = $matches[1];
    }
    return $subject;
}
$words = '      my words     ';
$words = preg_trim($words);
var_dump($words);
// string(8) "my words"
```

Comment: I needed to trim a simple space from the beginning and end of a string (I somehow skipped over the top voted answer here to use PHP's built in trim function). Prior to that, I used your function. It was returning an empty string. This function only works if there is more than one space at the beginning and end of a string. Not a terrible idea to have a function like this that strips out all spaces, but it needs to work with just one space, too.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason two solutions above didnt worked for me, so i came up with this solution.

```
function cleanSpaces($string) {
    while(substr($string, 0,1)==" ") 
    {
        $string = substr($string, 1);
        cleanSpaces($string);
    }
    while(substr($string, -1)==" ")
    {
        $string = substr($string, 0, -1);
        cleanSpaces($string);
    }
    return $string;
}
```

Comment: Be aware that while this may work, the overhead for the recursion makes this extremely slow and inefficient.  I am not sure why trim didn't work for you as it should work fine on any string.

Answer (score 0):

The question was about how to do it with regex, so:

```
$str1=~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
```

That says `^` at the begining `\s+` (white space) `|` or `\s+$` (whitespace at the end) `//g` remove repeatedly.  this same concept works in 'ed' (vi/vim)

sometimes it is better just to answer the question that was asked.

Answer (score -1):

If trim is not working for you as well , try this. 
You just need to write it to a different variable;

```
$str = ' hello world ';
echo strlen($str);

$trim_str = trim($str);
echo strlen($trim_str);
```